# Get list of opened windows and minimised windows

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-graphics

I'm using CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo to obtain list of windows opened in OSX system. I would like to get all opened windows + minimised window (windows which appears in the bottom of the dock). I've already tried all possible options of this function (https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1666230-quartz_window_services/1805250-window_list_option_constants?language=objc)

Using it with option kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly returns obviously proper list but without minimised windows. Without it, I get minimised but also all different windows which are not minimised (e.g. splash screens of other applications).

Second attempt was to use properties of window returned by CGWindowListCreateDescriptionFromArray(https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1455215-cgwindowlistcreatedescriptionfro?language=objc) but I didn't find the way also.

Thanks.

Update:

Also using accessibility API isn't a solution here since the user has to explicitly allow particular application to control the computer in system preferences.